# How to specify input as datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My project involves reading CSV files concering city data and then computing various statistics. I am trying to create a function that will take city data from a CSV and the create a copy of the data except with a date filter applied. The user is prompted to enter a starting and ending date.

I am currently just testing and trying to get the data to print with the correct date filters applied. My biggest problem so far is that I can't seem to convert the strings entered by the user into a datetime format. Is there a way for the user to directly enter the data in datetime format?

```
def date_filtering(city_file):
    date1 = input('Please enter a valid start date that you wish to explore?\n'
    date2 = input('Please enter a valid end date.')    
    print(city_file.loc[date1:date2])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only the last two lines of the code are relevant to your question. Please produce the minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you need both date and time or just date?

Comment: @DyZ That code example is perfectly reasonable. You don't need the absolute minimal example, just short enough that it isn't a challenge to follow.

Comment: @SamCraig This code example is _not_ reasonable. The amount of irrelevant comments and the function definition as such distract me from concentrating on the actual problem.

Comment: @DyZ That is fine, I can answer his problem fine. You can find another problem code-golfed to be as short as possible to help with.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I have edited it. I apologize. I am quite new to all of this. I have truncated my code down.

Comment: Okay, so the thing is you may not need to even convert your strings to datetime, because pandas is smart enough to infer dtypes. However, that would depend on your data which you have not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working of the assumption you only need date, because you make no mention of time in the code. What you need to do is parse the input somehow to get the year, month, and day. I am sure it could be done using regex, but it is simpler to do it just with python builtins.

A normal way of representing date in the US is mm/dd/yyyy, so I will use that.

```
def strtodatetime(str):
     month, day, year = [int(d) for d in str.split("/")]
     return datetime.date(year, month, day)

date1 = strtodatetime(input('Please enter a valid start date that you wish to explore?\n'))
date2 = strtodatetime(input('Please enter a valid end date.'))
```

The strtodatetime splits the input string by the "/" character, then casts each element in the resultant list to integers. Then it returns a new datetime.date object with the corresponding dates.

If you are worried about the user inputting something of the wrong format, you can use a try block to make sure they don't. There are three possible sources of exceptions I can see, the user can input too many or too few /'s (like 10/2/1999/2), the user can input a date that doesn't exist (like 13/32/-1), or the user can input something that can't be cast to an int (like March/22/1999). All three raise ValueErrors, so that is the only exception we need to catch here. To catch that, we would change our code to

```
def strtodatetime(str):
     month, day, year = [int(d) for d in str.split("/")]
     return datetime.date(year, month, day)

date_filtering(city_file):
    try:
        date1 = strtodatetime(input('Please enter a valid start date that you wish to explore?\n'))
        date2 = strtodatetime(input('Please enter a valid end date.'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid date in the format mm/dd/yyyy')
        return date_filtering(city_file)
    return city_file.loc[date1:date2]

print(data_filtering(city_file))
```

Comment: You should add a `try` statement in your function or an `if` statement testing if there is '/' in the 3rd and the 6th position. Other than that, good

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ Testing for "/" locations will have a lot of false positives/negatives, (for example, it would raise an error for 1/1/2000, which is valid, and not for 13/33/-001 or ab/cd/efgh, which are not valid). I edited my comment to include exception handling which should do well.

Comment: I have used your string to date time function but still get the following error when I try to apply the dates to the CSV file but still get the following error.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: @KevinNgo That sound like an issue with the something else, because you are not comparing any dates in the code above. You code create different question related to that and link it here and I will try to help.

Comment: 1) You should be using MM/DD/YYYY Which you should type '02/03/2018'

Comment: 2) I 'forgot to mention' but you should also check if the other characters are numbers :)

Comment: Whatever, it's just a tiny addition

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ 1) The presence of leading 0s are irrelevant in the code. 2) As my question addresses, the code will handle non-integer inputs with the try except block.